# When should I save image to database

Tags: android, database

I'm new to android programing.

when and why we save image to database and when and why we save image as a file in android programing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application, you might want to allow the user to download images from the internet and save them locally in a database **(sqlite database)** then later view them in ImageView or in ListView. However, this approach should be used only with small images. For big images, you should save their path in the database and the image data in sdcard instead.